# how to remove space if we hide edittext in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, invisible

i am doing like these in my xml i using spinner.In spinner if i select other edittext should be visible.before that edittext space must be remove.

```
eidttext.setVisibility(android.view.View.INVISIBLE);
eidttext.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE);
```

i want to remove space of the edittext when it is inVisible.if any have idea.

Comment: edittext is invisible space is not remove.i have two more edittext in below spinner.if i hide edittext.these two edit text must be occupied these space.

Answer (score 5):

You use `View.GONE` to free the space for other widgets, `View.INVISIBLE` will keep the space, but make the widget, well, invisible. [View's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
View edittext;
```

Instead of Button edittext;

```
edittext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This will help you

Answer (score 0):

In XML use to hide a element with their shape height or width:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```